# show alert when value is number

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show the alert box when the user typed the number in the input field

```
<input type="text" class="only-text">
```

```
if (document.querySelector('.only-text').value === '') {alert('no numbers are allowed!')};
```

Comment: Use a regular expression to check if there are numbers in the value.

Comment: the script code should be invoked inside an event. for example - onChange or focusOut should be the events

Comment: no-one wants pop-up boxes that need closing because they fat fingered a number

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the `beforeinput` event, this way you can check the value inserted before it is painted in the DOM, and if it's not good you can prevent it from being painted.

```js
function isBeforeInputEventAvailable() {
  return window.InputEvent && typeof InputEvent.prototype.getTargetRanges === "function";
}

if (isBeforeInputEventAvailable()) onlyText.addEventListener("beforeinput", e => {
  if (/[\d]+/.test(e.data)) {
    alert('no numbers are allowed!')
    e.preventDefault()
  };
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="onlyText">
```